# SqlDataAdapter.Fill running SQL command twice

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, insert, duplicates

I'm trying to insert a new row in my SQL database from ASP.NET but it's inserting the row twice instead of once.

I haven't been able to find which line of the code below is causing this.

Here's my code:

```
 public static void Register(User user)
        {
            string query = "insert into TblTutors (username,email,pass,sub,category,city,fullname,img,bio,tutor,way)

           values (@username,@email,@pass,@mat,@cat,@country,@fullname,Cast(@img As nvarchar(MAX)),@bio,@tutor,@way )";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user.username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", user.email);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tutor", user.tutor);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@way", user.way);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mat", user.mat);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", user.cat);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", user.country);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", "halima");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", user.fullname);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", user.img);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bio", user.bio);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

            }

        }
```

Comment: Remove the code around the SqlDataAdapter (Fill). The SqlDataAdapter when it calls Fill executes the query passed in the constructor. The correct way to execute an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE query is through ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: And [best not use AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DataAdapter.Fill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fill?view=net-5.0) is used to populate a `DataSet` with the *results* of the `SelectCommand` of the `DataAdapter`.

Since you're not looking to do any `SELECT` queries, remove the code regarding filling the `DataTable` as while it won't return any data, it *will* execute your `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` SQL commands inside `cmd` passed to `new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);`.

You're essentially writing data **twice**, once when you fill `dt` & again when you execute the query:

```
sda.Fill(dt);
...
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This should work as expected, removing the need for a `DataSet` as well.

```
public static void Register(User user)
{
    string query = "insert into TblTutors (username,email,pass,sub,category,city,fullname,img,bio,tutor,way)

   values (@username,@email,@pass,@mat,@cat,@country,@fullname,Cast(@img As nvarchar(MAX)),@bio,@tutor,@way )";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user.username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", user.email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tutor", user.tutor);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@way", user.way);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mat", user.mat);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", user.cat);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", user.country);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", "halima");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", user.fullname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", user.img);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bio", user.bio);

        con.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

}
```